# Prevent access to files generated by a Java application

Tags: java, windows, security, desktop

I'm working on an application that generates a series of files based on user input that would be later uploaded to a cloud service.

It is important that these files remain intact (prevent modification or deletion) before they are uploaded.

What would be the best way to accomplish this? I could work with Windows only solutions. I know that a sufficiently motivated advanced user would be able to do it anyways but I'm looking for solutions to obscure or just make it harder than 'Select all > Delete'.

All these generated files will be within the same folder.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I previously stated that I didn't mind the files could be read but that would enable copying and storing them somewhere else and that is undesirable too.

Comment: Does this: https://dzone.com/articles/locking-files-in-java solve tour problem?

Comment: You should look into locking the files. Also I recommend that you look into signing the files and then verifying the signature when you want to use it: private - public key, etc...

Comment: Locking would be a first step, and signing and checking before uploading seems to be the way to go too. Thanks. Now, I was thinking if the folder could be hidden to at least difficult the task of copying the files somewhere else?

Comment: According to your latest edit, then I would also recommend putting the files in a folder and encrypting the folder. Look in to the `BouncyCastle` library.

Comment: Would it be somewhat useful to, following [this](https://github.com/weiliatgithub/bouncycastle-gpg-example) example, to encrypt+sign when generating the files and storing them and decrypting+verifying them when uploading? (all keys would be hardcoded). I know this is not secure. My goal now is just to make things a little hard for the average user.

Comment: Sounds good. If the idea is just to obscure things then that is what you are doing, because by no means is a very good way of maintaining security in all its senses.